# Creating dataframe from output and save the file as CSV

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe and save as csv.My code and output is given below: 
CODE:

```
for dtags in html.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'wrap'}):
        for index, ptags in enumerate(dtags.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'partial_entry'})):
            if index == 0: #match the first element
                x = ptags.text
                z = print('Review:', x)
```

My Output is given below:
OutPut:

```
Review: I went on a family trip and it was amazing, I hope to come back soon. The room was small but what can you expect from New York. It was close to many things and the staff was perfect.I will come back again soon.
Review: Stayed here with my boyfriend for four nights, nice hotel. Didn’t have breakfast included so can’t comment on that. All staff very pleasant, rooms cleaned every day new towels every day. No complaints from us two. Wouldn’t come to New York again though. 
Review: Stayed in this hotel for 4 nights over new year 2017. It is in a good location, a
```

Now I am using a code to create dataframe but I am unable to do so,my code to create dataframe is given below:

```
import pandas as pd
results = []
results.append(z)
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
```

This code is not working fine.Need help to create a dataframe for my output and save it as CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the slightly modified version of your code:

```
results = []
for dtags in html.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'wrap'}):
        for index, ptags in enumerate(dtags.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'partial_entry'})):
            if index == 0: #match the first element
                x = ptags.text
                results.append({"review": x})
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.to_csv('data.csv', mode='a', header = False)
print(df)
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not working..Didn't get anything in CSV file

Comment: what does print(df) return ? Is it also empty?

Comment: Can you please send me the code block you are executing now ? Just make sure that you don't override results variable with an empty array.

Comment: If I have 15 reviews,then it overwrite the reviews in my csv file and I am only getting last 5 reviews.How to overcome that issue?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about what you are trying to do and also maybe paste some code snippets? Because I don't get how would that happen if you read it once and write it once. Are you trying to run this code multiple times and get new data ?

Comment: df.to_csv('data.csv',mode='a', header=False) should do the work, I updated my answer, please try it

Comment: Great, glad to help.